# Release called on circular reference

Tags: ios, memory-management

`[a retain]` in object b

in object a

`[b retain]`  
 resulting in circular reference.
what happens if
 `[a release]`

is called by some method in object b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some method in `b` calls `[a release]`, then the retain cycle is broken.  When nothing else owns `a`, `a` will be deallocated.  Presumably, in `a`'s `dealloc`, it does `[b release]`.  Then if nothing else owns `b`, `b` will also be deallocated.

Sometimes a retain cycle is ok.  You just need to make sure the cycle will be broken at the appropriate time.  For example, an object can own a single-use `NSTimer`, and the timer can own the object (as the timer's `target`), creating a retain cycle.  When the timer fires, the object should release the timer, breaking the retain cycle.  If the object cancels the timer (by sending it `invalidate`) before the timer fires, the timer releases the object, also breaking the retain cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a retain cycle in such a case which should be avoided as this is a form of a memory leak.

Here is a good write up:
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html

I would strongly recommend redesigning your classes to avoid the circular requirement,